# How to check if a list of strings contains certain value?

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to see if  a ArrayList of strings contains a word located in another string , but i am doing something wrong. Here is my code: 
Here is an example of my ArrayList

titles = {"Sodium " , " Lithium " , "Allura Red AC"};

```
String ocrRes = "I want some sugar  , and some coffee with Allura Red AC , Ponceau 4R ";

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size() ; i++)
    {

            if (ocrRes.contains(titles.get(i)) )
            {
                ocrResult.setText(titles.get(i));
            }


    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not your actual code. Arrays don't have `size()` or `get()` methods.

Comment: Yes , sir. I forgot to say that i use an ArrayList , i typed list by mistake. Excuse me. And thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Well, in your snippet above, you're initializing `titles` as an array. If you were to change `titles.size()` to `titles.length`, and `titles.get(i)` to `titles[i]`, that snippet would work (assuming the `TextView` is initialized correctly). We need to see the actual code to determine what your current problem is.

Comment: First, post your actual code.  Second, your code seems to be attempting to do the opposite of what the question says.  Do you want to find out if a list contains a string, or if a string contains a value from the list?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of how you would find a specific word in a string array:

```
String[] array;
//will return the index of the array where word found.

int checkWord(String searchWord)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   { 
           if (searchWord.equals(array[i]))
               return i;
   }
}
```

You could implement something like this to find a word in your array, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @Aaron. This works , but i can't use this , because i need to check if my sentence(String ocrRes) contains any of the words that are located in my list. All that because later i will need to get the index of the title[i] which indicates a position of another word but in other list. 
For example i have two Lists 
titles = {"Sodium " , " Lithium " , "Allura Red AC"};
causes = {"Headache", "Skin Rush" , "Blurry vision""}

so Sodium causes Headache , Lithium - Skin Rush etc..
Thats why i need the index. :)

Comment: It works , thank you sir.  I found out that in my ArrayList all string were with lower-case letters. However , thank you :)

Comment: glad it worked :) @Freddie maybe except my answer if you feel the need to

Answer (score 1):

Your'e code seems to work fine...
you probably didn't use the ArrayList as u should

use like this:

```
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    titles.add("Sodium");
    titles.add("Lithium");
    titles.add("Allura Red AC");

    String ocrRes = "I want some sugar  , and some coffee with Allura Red AC , Ponceau 4R ";

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (ocrRes.contains(titles.get(i)) )
        {
           ocrResult.setText(titles.get(i));
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

Iv'e seen on your comments to other answeres u need another list with corresponding indexes so just create an array list the same why as I showed u in the code above...

Btw the the way u seem to init your list is like your initing an array
which is different type and looks like this:

```
String[] array = {"Sodium " , " Lithium " , "Allura Red AC"};
```

gl

Comment: In my ArrayList all strings were with lower-case letters. Ahh , thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using ListIterator

```
    String ocrRes = "I want some sugar  , and some coffee with Allura Red AC , Ponceau 4R ";

    List<String> titles = Arrays.asList("Sodium", "Lithium", "Allura Red AC");
    ListIterator<String> iterator = titles.listIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String title = iterator.next();

        if(ocrRes.contains(title)) {
            System.out.println(title);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.  If a ArrayList of strings contains a word located in another `String`. It will display the that `String` only.

**Sample  Code**

```
String str = "I want some sugar  , and some coffee with Allura Red AC , Ponceau 4R ";
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Sodium", "Lithium", "Allura Red AC");
    myList.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
            public void accept(String s) {
                if(str.contains(s)) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

        });
```